# Android Studio Emulator is gliching so bad

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator, lag

[image]Please look at the picture. I am using latest version of Android Studio, and the emulator inside is so damn glichy. The black lines as shown in the picture appear and disappear hundreds of times in one minute, help me fix this.

I tried installing and reinstalling different emulators, all seem to have this problem. I even installed and reinstalled android studio, still nothing has changed. I cannot find help on internet other than asking it here. The picture I provided as a direct screenshot of my issue, only yellow lines were drawn by me to hide the information inside the app,

Comment: I could not find the answer to this issue from nowhere, so I just installed BlueStacks 5, and it is working as smoothly as a knife through butter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing an experimenting with different Android Studio versions, I found a solution. It is October 2023 right now, and Android Studio hedgehog is still in beta, so I am using Giraffe. The emulator works perfectly fine with Giraffe. If I use a hedgehog, then it starts flickering again. Apparently, the issue lies with Nvidia GPU drivers. If such flickering happens, delete your emulator and create a new one, but remember to use SOFTWARE to run your emulator. Do not use a Hardware accelerated emulator. It will be slower than with the GPU version, but definitely better than glitching/flickering like crazy.

Another option is to use Bluestacks or something.

Answer (score 1):

the best that you can do its just to plug your android phone (if you have one...) and the android studio will recognize him and run the app on your phone. if android studio not recognize your phone, go to developer options in your phone and enable the USB debug option. the android emulators always was terrible...